# How to look for specific keywords in a string and replace it with the existing string value?

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("A112","A114","A134","A116","A117","A138")
Comment <- c("Beam calibration again", "Beam calibration. Tools ready",
             "Did not find anything wrong. Beam calibration","Performed beam calibration. tool ready",
             "STD Qual and Blurry image looks fine","STD Qual failed and Slightly Blurry image")
df<- data.frame(ID,Comment)
df

    ID                                      Comment
  A112                       Beam calibration again
  A114               Beam calibration. Tools ready
  A134 Did not find anything wrong. Beam calibration
  A116       Performed beam calibration. tool ready
  A117         STD Qual and Blurry image looks fine
  A138    STD Qual failed and Slightly Blurry image
```

Since the comments are too long, I want to reduce it to pick specific keywords like "Blurry image", "Beam Calibration". I want my **desired output** to be

```
    ID          Comment
  A112 Beam calibration
  A114 Beam calibration
  A134 Beam calibration
  A116 beam calibration
  A117     Blurry image
  A138     blurry image
```

I tried it this way for one column but how do I programmatically apply a similar logic for all columns?

```
df$Comment <- gsub("Beam calibration again", "Beam calibration", df$Comment)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific list of keywords you want to look for? If you don't this could be rather challenging. If you wanted to look for just "Beam calibration" and "Blurry image" you could try: `gsub(".*(Beam calibration|Blurry image).*", "\\1", df$Comment, ignore.case = TRUE)`

Comment: @MikeH. I am looking for specific keywords only. Your solution works perfectly for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample data, if you are only looking for `Beam calibration` and `Blurry image` you could do:

```
df$Comment <- gsub(".*(Beam calibration|Blurry image).*", "\\1", df$Comment, ignore.case = TRUE)

df
#    ID          Comment
#1 A112 Beam calibration
#2 A114 Beam calibration
#3 A134 Beam calibration
#4 A116 beam calibration
#5 A117     Blurry image
#6 A138     Blurry image
```

Or to avoid typing by hand, if you have a vector of keywords you could build your lookup like:

```
keywords <- c("Beam calibration", "Blurry image")
lookup <- paste0(".*(", paste(keywords, collapse = "|"), ").*")
df$Comment <- gsub(lookup, "\\1", df$Comment, ignore.case = TRUE)
```